# Delay the time of masking an input field

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a problem trying to change after 1sec of delay the value that I enter in an input. I put you on context. I have this HTML code:

```
<form [formGroup]="formSca" autocomplete="off" class="row formSign" ngNativeValidate>
  <div *ngFor="let pos of signatureDataArr; let i = index" class="pos-rect">
    <input formcontrolName="posicion" type="text" [disabled]="pos.state=='hidden'" class="square"
      maxlength="1" [ngModel]="pos.content | mask"
      (ngModelChange)="pos.content = $event" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
      (keypress)="pos.content === '' ? checkValue($event, i): ''">
  </div>
</form>
```

The mask pipe just update the ngModel transforming the value to an asterisk with a reg expresion:

```
val.replace(/./, '*');
```

In this way, I have the value entered saved in the array of objects and shown the asterisk.

What I want is to let the user see the value entered for a second and after that, do the masking and show the asterisk, but with the value saved in the array.

CheckValueFucntion:

```
checkValue(value, index) {
    this.signatureDataArr[index].content = value.key;
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debounce.html

Comment: @Vikas dosen't work, at least what I have tried watching that exaples in the page